# External HTML with relative paths loaded with Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, .net, ajax

I'm wondering what is the best approach when you're loading an external HTML file with relative paths ( which is given by an `api` response ) through `ajax`

For example we have following folder content somewhere on the disk ( not in project's root ):

`-Folder
       -test.html
       /Images/img1.png
             /img2.png
       /css/test.css
       /js/test.js`

The `HTML` file ( test.html ) from above has relative paths to coresponding files ( `<img src='images/img1.png'>`, `<script src='js/test.js'>` and so on )

We're making a request from  `mvc view page` to controller which makes a request to a `web api` method, which returns the html content. ( View -> Controller -> Web API -> Response from api returned to controller -> Response returned to View )

We're loading the HTML in a `div` ( .html )

At this point, browser console will turn red because of `404 - not found` messages.

What do you think it's the best approach to fix this ?

I fixed it by copying everything in project's root path, but I don't think this is the best solution.

Comment: Use Root relative paths id all this is in the one site. E.g `src="/Images/Image1.png"`